# how to hide login view name in using pretty faces

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces, pretty-urls

I have one application running on tomcat sever.I removed the path in in server.xml so i am able to access the application like

```
http://localhost:8080/login.xhtml
```

I am using Pretty faces as well for URL rewrite.
Now i want to know how to send a request to server like

```
http://localhost:8080
```

so that it should display my login page.
My pretty-config.xml is

```
<url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/" />
    <view-id value="/login.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

it is not working.please let me know the solution.

Comment: I think it should be done like this: "http://localhost:8080/" this will map to your login page according to your config file.

Answer (score 1):

Your pretty-config part (which is valid) tells that a path `/` should be mapped to `/login.xhtml` and may be referred to as `pretty:login` in outcomes of JSF components (as well as in action methods).

From here there are two possible options for inconsistencies:

1. Prettyfaces must be pointed to a valid URL, meaning that FacesServlet mapping in web.xml should be `*.xhtml` in your case, not `faces/*`, not `*.jsf`, etc.
2. Prettyfaces should be used appropriately in your JSF components. For instance, `<h:link outcome="pretty:login" value="Home" />` will render an HTML `a` element with the value `/` (which will internally show `login.xhtml` when you click on it).

Also, it would be helpful to read the excellent [PrettyFaces documentation](http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html_single/#outbound_rewriting).

Comment: i changed the web.xml, and, it worked.Thanks all for your help